# Setting up Error Pages for CloudFront when it is using an S3 REST API endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution which is pointing to an S3 bucket holding my website's static content. This is done using S3 REST API endpoints, so the origin's domain name and path looks like this:

```
bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com
```

So far, this is working and I know this because when I open the browser and enter `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/index.html`, it downloads the html file. But this is not all that I'm after. My website is an SPA (single page application) written in React. This means not all the resources mentioned in the client-side code can actually be found on the bucket. Those resources that are not physically available in the bucket are virtual resources and are supposed to be handled by the client-side code.

For this to work, if the user enters the address of a virtual URL into the browser, the server first needs to verify whether that resource exists or not. If it does not, the server should return `index.html` file instead of 404 error. This can be set up in the CloudFront's Error Pages.

So I created a Custome Error Response for my CloudFront distribution handling all the 404 errors, returning the `index.html` file with 200 ok status. But this does not work.

When enter the URL `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/virtual-url`, it returns:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>39E3967AA5F16693</RequestId>
<HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

Even the naked URL `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net` returns the exact same error.

So my question is, how can I use Error Pages of CloudFront when the distribution is using an S3 REST API endpoint?

P.S. When I was using the S3's static website endpoint (`bucket-name.s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`), the same mechanism worked.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "This is done using REST API endpoints"? Are you using API Gateway in front of the CloudFront distribution?

Comment: There are two ways to mention an S3 bucket in a CloudFront distribution. Please refer to this page for more info: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/

Comment: @Mehran this *should* be working... but unless your Origin Access Identity has the `s3:ListBucket` permission, the error you need to handle with the CloudFront custom error page is 403, not 404.  Check that?

Comment: Check that CloudFront has read permissions for your custom error objects (like index.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Why should I handle 403? I believe I need to handle 404. I mean I want to return `index.html` whenever the request was pointing to a file that does not exist, but 403 means forbidden. And regarding the permission, correct me if I'm wrong but if there was a problem with permission, I should have not been able to see the `index.html` when I point directly at it. But as I explained in my post, when the URL ends in `index.html` it is fetched! BTW, thanks.

Comment: I think it's due to a lack of List permission like Michael said. When you try to access a non-existant resource like a virtual url, a 404 would expose information about the bucket contents, so you get a 403 instead. So Michael-sqlbot is correct, need to handle the 403 (or add list permission, but that's not a good practice).
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726269/why-cloudfront-returns-custom-error-object-only-when-list-permission-is-granted

Comment: Here's what you are overlooking: You are **not** getting that error because access is denied to the custom error file, /index.html.  You are getting that error because S3 REST endpoints *never* throw a 404 unless the requester has `s3:ListBucket` or the bucket ACL allows public access.  By default, S3 throws 403 and `<Code>AccessDenied</Code>` when an object does not exist, not 404, because without a grant of permission to list the objects in the bucket, S3 considers the requester unauthorized to know the specific reason the request failed.

Comment: @bwest, yes.  And adding the list permission really isn't a good practice, but CloudFront's [Default Root Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDefaultRootObject) setting prevents a listing from being pulled through CloudFront, since bucket listings are queried using a path of `/`.